# Undefined when building for mips

Tags: go

Trying to cross compile my go app for mips.

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=mipsle go build ./
```

However, I get the following issues:

```
# github.com/google/gopacket/afpacket
/root/go/src/github.com/google/gopacket/afpacket/options.go:176:19: undefined: pageSize
/root/go/src/github.com/google/gopacket/afpacket/options.go:177:85: undefined: pageSize
# github.com/google/gopacket/pcap
/root/go/src/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap/pcap.go:30:22: undefined: pcapErrorNotActivated
/root/go/src/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap/pcap.go:52:17: undefined: pcapTPtr
/root/go/src/github.com/google/gopacket/pcap/pcap.go:64:10: undefined: pcapPkthdr
```

What's the actual issue here? Is there some architecture limitations in `gopacket` that prevents me from building it for mips?

Comment: It looks like `pagesize` is an uninitialized variable. My IDE also said that it doesn't exists. Maybe that's an error in the Google repo, is this an option ?

Comment: It seems like the variable is defined [in this line](https://github.com/google/gopacket/blob/6eef11e26c8c0772cc627edf0fb231ad8eda357b/afpacket/afpacket.go#L44), which calls [this function](https://github.com/golang/sys/blob/c7b8b68b14567162c6602a7c5659ee0f26417c18/unix/pagesize_unix.go#L13). The build tag in line 5 indicates that it does not work on mips. However, support was added [here](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/1b9499b06989d2831e5b156161d6c07642926ee1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that gopacket is not a pure go project, it relies on CGO for running.
Enable CGO by passing env may be help:

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=mipsle go build ./
```

At the same time, you need to prepare a mipsle version libpcap.

1. download cross complie toolchain: [mipsle-linux-gcc](https://www.mips.com/develop/tools/compilers/linux-toolchain/)
2. compile libpcap:

```sh
wget http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.8.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf libpcap-1.8.1.tar.gz
cd libpcap-1.8.1
./configure --host=mipsle-linux --with-pcap=linux
make  #if error occured, install dependency following the error message.
```

After compile, you'll find `libpcap.a` and `libpcap.so.1.8.1` build up.

3. compile your project with libpcap linked

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=mipsle-linux-gcc GOARCH=mipsle GOOS=linux CGO_LDFLAGS="-L./libpcap-1.8.1" go build ./
```